# getting elevation from a point

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, spatial

I am using javascript connected to google map api v3 and I have the following 2 methods. Now my target is that from the point I give the method, it will pop up the elevation of that particular point.

BUT for some reason it is not giving any output.

The reason I used hard coded point since I am testing the result. Actually at the end the point I will gert it from a database.

Any suggestions why this is happening?

```
    var elevator;
    var map;

    function InitializeMap() {

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var myOptions =
            {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

        elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService();

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', getElevation);

    }



    function getElevation(event) {

        var locations = [];


        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

            var location = 'POINT(14.5084692510445, 35.8988013191481)';

            locations.push(location);

            var positionalRequest = { 'locations': locations }

            elevator.getElevationForLocation(positionalRequest, function (results, status) {

                if (status == google.maps.ElevationStauts.OK) {


                    if (results[0]) {

                        alert(results[0].elevation);

                   }

                }

            });

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the name of the method is

   ```
   elevator.getElevationForLocations
   //------------------------------^
   ```
2. a typo:

   ```
   google.maps.ElevationStauts
   //----------------------^^
   ```
3. `positionalRequest.location` must be an array of `google.maps.LatLng`-objects

   ```
   var location = new google.maps.LatLng(14.5084692510445, 35.8988013191481);
   ```

Comment: How would you recommend that I should pass values of points that I get from a database in backend using c# to javascript? thanks @Dr.Molle

Comment: I don't know about c#, but JSON would be fine . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016595/return-json-using-c-sharp-like-php-json-encode