# How to send array HttpPost to Apache Server

Tags: c#, php, http-post

I can't sending my array with DoPostMethod. Php code is working but I can't convert it to C#.Php code is

```
 $numbers = array('50XXXXXXXX', '50XXXXXXXX', '50XXXXXXXX', '50XXXXXXXX');
$message = 'TEST';
$title = 'MAS API'; 
 $veriler = array(
'apiNo' =>'1',
'user' =>’user_name’,
'pass' =>'pasword',
'mesaj'=>$message,
'numaralar' =>$numbers,
'baslik' =>$title,
); 
$ozel_mesaj = sms_gonder("http://------",$veriler);
```

My code is below

```
DoRequest(string requestUrl, string requestMethod, string requestData){     
  WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);

                request.Method = requestMethod;


                string postData = requestData;
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);


                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";


                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;


                Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();


                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);


                dataStream.Close();


                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();


                Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);


                dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();


                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);


                this.ServerResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();


                reader.Close();
                dataStream.Close();
                response.Close();}
```

but i can send with ajax method

```
$.ajax({
                "url": "myUrl",
                "type": "post",
                data:{
                    "apiNo": "apiNo",
                    "user": "user_name",
                    "pass": "password",
                    "mesaj": "DENEME123",
                    "numaralar":"numbers",
                    "baslik":"baslik"
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != NULL)
                        alert(data)
                    else
                        alert("Kayıt Eklenemedi")
                }
```

I think my requestData is wrong. My RequestData is below:

```
 string xmlRequest = "[{{apiNo=\"apiNo\"}, {user=\"user_name\"},{pass=\"password\"},{mesaj=\"DENEME2\"},{numaralar=\"{0000000000}\"},{baslik=\"baslik\"}}]";
```

How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: {numaralar=\"{0000000000}\"} is different from your others paramaters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using this

```
     string URL = "myURL";
     WebClient webClient = new WebClient();


     NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
    formData["apiNo"] = "apiNo";
        formData["user"] = "user";
        formData["pass"] = "pass";
        formData["baslik"] = "baslik";
        formData["numaralar"] = "{numaralar}";
        formData["mesaj"] =" mesaj";

     byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(URL, "POST", formData);
     string responsefromserver = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
     Console.WriteLine(responsefromserver);
     webClient.Dispose();
```

and you can look at this [link](http://www.softwareandfinance.com/PHP/PostRequest_CSharp_php.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a super basic way to do it. In this example, I am manually writing out the post parameters with a quick function that returns a string however, you could use [JavascriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) to properly convert a C# array (as well as reading inbound json returned by your webservice) which was recommended in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016595/return-json-using-c-sharp-like-php-json-encode) answer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;

namespace doPostExampleForStackOverflow
{
static class Program
{

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        string postReturn = doPostCall();
        MessageBox.Show(postReturn);
        Application.Exit();
    }

    static string doPostCall()
    {
        string URI = "https://webserver.com/post.php";
        string myParameters = "username=" + Environment.UserName; /* Get local username (Windows) */
            string result;

            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                result = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
            }
            if (result.Length <= 0) {
                return "Nothing came back from the webserver.";
            } else {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain further? Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: I didn't get an error but service didn't send message to my phone.

Comment: I apologize for the late response. I noticed that I had included "using System.Linq;" in my example. This may have interfered if you included it. The code above came from a working application I wrote using VS2015.